# Jquery .Post not display returned data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, kendo-grid

Using kendo open source with mvc3.

I have a kendo grid with selectable rows.  When a row is selected, it should send a value to the controller method, then render a new view based on that value.  I know for certain that the controller method is hit, returns the correct data and serves up the correct view.  Using the chrome web developer tools I can see the rendered page int he response, but the view in the browser never changes.  SO it works all the way until it is tie to actually see.

my js in the kendo scripting:

```
        selectable: true,
        change: function (e) {
            var row = this.select();
            var detailId = this.dataItem(row).PersonId;

            $.post('@Url.Action("Detail", "Person")', { id: detailId });

        }
```

the controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Detail(int id)
    {

        var model = new Person();

        model = db.Person.Where(x => x.PersonId == id).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(model);
    }
```

any idea why it wont render?

=======EDIT===========

I did not use an ajax function here because I do not want any kind of response coming back to the js function.  I want the id sen to the server side method, I want the method to run, then serve up the new view, then I want it sent to the client and rendered.  It is doing everything but the last step, rendering on the client.  Should I be using a different jquery method?

Answer (score 1):

though im not very proficient in kendo grid im sure you would somehow need to handle the response by `$.post()`.

you should use this overload of the `$.post(url,data,handler)`;
you ideally you will have something like this in you js code

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Detail", "Person")', { id: detailId }, function(data){
 //now render the data wherever you want
});
```

Comment: thanks Parv, but I dont want the response coming back to the client side function.

Comment: as mentioned in your question you want your new view to be rendered.. rit?? then the data you are getting back from $.post add it somewhere so that it shows up on the page